# Is this definition on an octal byte correct?

Tags: binary, byte, octal

My instructor stated that "an octal byte consists of 6 bits". I am having difficulty understanding why this is, as an octal digit consists of 3 binary bits. I also do not understand the significance of an octal byte being defined as '6 bits' as opposed to some other number.

Can anyone explain why this is, if it is in fact true, or point me to a useful explanation?

Comment: There is no official definition of a byte being 8 bits.  That said, I've never heard of an "octal byte" before.

Comment: Instructors like to stick to academic books.  Academic books like to make stuff up and insist that they become standard terminology.  Nobody besides `Publisher XYZ` and its loyal following of instructors ever uses the term `octal byte`.  You can safely forget this once you have passed the class.

Comment: From the manpage of od: `-b          Output octal bytes.  Equivalent to -t o1.`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is all speculation and guesswork, since none of this is in any way standard terminology.

An 8-bit byte can be written as two digits of hexadecimals, because each digit expresses 4 bits. The largest such byte value is `0xFF`.

By analogy, two digits of octals can express 2 × 3 = 6 bits. Its largest value is `077`. So if you like you can call a pair of two octals an "octal byte", but only if you will also call an 8-bit byte a "hexadecimal byte".

In my personal opinion neither notion is helpful or useful, and you'd be best of just to say how many bits your byte has.

Answer (score 0):

as for wiki : *The byte is a unit of digital information that most commonly consists of 8 bits. The bit  is a contraction of binary digit. The bit represents a logical state with one of two possible values. These values are most commonly represented as either "1" or "0".*

so byte is a set of bunch of bits. to be specific of 8 bits.

we see that the definition doesnt say anything about dec oct hex and other notations of integer number.

indeed byte and integer number is not the same. so where
does it start ?

if we type bits of byte  like so  01001010 we can find that
we can map 1-to-1 this object to binary notation
of integer numbers 01001010.

(byte)01001010  --> (binary integer) 01001010

the two objects look the same but actually is just mapping.

now we work with integer number instead of abstract object "byte". an integer
number can be designated via different notations like : dec, binary, hex, oct etc.

notation like octal(hex,dec etc) is just a method of designation of integer number. it does not influence the nature of initial byte object.

byte has 8 bits whatever notation is used.

ISO/IEC 2382-1:1993 says:
1.The number of bits in a byte is usually 8.
2.Octet is Byte  that consists of eight
Bits

Answer (score 0):

A 6 bit byte was used in many ancient computers. For instance the IBM Punch card used a 6 bit character set. The number of characters was limited to 64. As binary it is 000000 through 111111. Decimal 0 through 63. Octal would be 00 through 77. Each Octal digit represent 3 bits. So Octal is a great way to represent 6 bit bytes, the same way one Hexadecimal digit represents 4 bits when you are talking about 8 bit bytes. I would say that calling it an Octal Byte is a bit of a misnomer; octal is simply a great way to represent 6 bit bytes.
The only place I ever see octal these days is for permissions in unix. You have read, write and execute privileges for the "file owner", "group members" and "everybody else". RWX="Read Write execute". Each of these privileges can be turned on or off for a file for Owner, group and others. 0=off and 1-on. This is the source of the symbol for power on/off "⏻" so If you give the owner of the file read, write and execute permissions you would have 111 in binary or 7 in octal. Example: to give permissions of Read/write/execute to the owner and only Read and execute to group and everyone else for the file named "file.txt" you could use the command:

```
$ chmod 755 file.txt
```

In Binary those permissions would be:

```
111101101
RWXRWXRWX
```

All that said, in the current computing world a byte always refers to an 8 bit byte that is represented best by using Hexadecimal.

If someone is talking about an "octal byte" or more correctly a 6-bit byte usually they are talking about computer history and this is often taught in an architecture class to further understand the role of the "bit" in computing.

Answer (score -1):

Like @Kerrek SB I'd have to guess the same.

Tell him an octal byte is two octal nibbles, that should sort him out.

Two hexadecimal digits is an 8 bit byte, so each four bits were called a nibble.